# Will an OSGIfied jar work as a normal jar?

Tags: java, jar, osgi, manifest

I am evaluating the possibility of modifying the MANIFEST.MF files of a set of common Java libraries in order for them to become valid OSGI bundles (by adding the required headers).

Nevertheless, the implications of this aren't clear for me... Will these .jars work seamlessly as the non-OSGIfied ones did in non-OSGI environments?

These jars are being deployed in a range of Application Servers, from IBMs WebSphere to JBoss or Tomcat. Will this OSGIfication trigger an involuntary change in the default behaviour of these applications servers towards these .jars?

And yes, these are jars with external dependencies (on open source projects which might not be OSGIfied) and which also work as dependencies for other projects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will have zero effect.  The OSGi-ness is only captured in OSGi specific manifest entries; they mean nothing to a plain JVM classloader.  In fact, many open source JARs have been made OSGi-ed for some time and you don't need to know it has if you don't use it.  One which comes to mind is Javolution

Comment: In fact the JAR File Specification *mandates* that it will have zero effect... applications that do not understand a manifest entry are required to ignore it.

Comment: One of the few things that can be messed up is using Bundle-ClassPath. This ONLY works for OSGi. Ergo, never use Bundle-ClassPath